# Refused to connect to 'wss://live.mysite.com:3000/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, websocket, content-security-policy

```js
 if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(stream => {
        localStream = stream;
        document.getElementById('localVideo').srcObject = stream;
      }).catch(errorHandler)

      // set up websocket and message all existing clients
      .then(() => {
        serverConnection = new WebSocket('wss://' + window.location.hostname + ':' + WS_PORT);
        serverConnection.onmessage = gotMessageFromServer;
        serverConnection.onopen = event => {
          serverConnection.send(JSON.stringify({ 'displayName': localDisplayName, 'uuid': localUuid, 'dest': 'all' }));
        }
      }).catch(errorHandler);

  } else {
    alert('Your browser does not support getUserMedia API');
  }
}
```

I have configured SSL but not working.
I have tried meta tag but also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Refused to connect to 'wss://live.mysite.com:3000/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:

You cutted most informative part of error message, which contains exact info what happens and how to fix it.

Therefore I'll try to guess.

You use Express with Helmet 4. The last one has defaull Content Security Policy header [enabled](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet/wiki/Helmet-4-upgrade-guide#there-is-now-a-default-policy). The default policy has value `default-src 'self'`. The `'self'` token does not covers `wss://live.mysite.com:3000/` because it covers standard ports numbers only.

> I have tried meta tag but also didn't work

Adding meta tag you will get 2 CSPs published at the same time: via HTTP header and via meta tag. More strict one will be applied, so meta tag fix nothing.

Just disable CSP in Helmet:

```
app.use(helmet({
  contentSecurityPolicy: false,
}));
```

and turn it on when you figure out what how it works. Alternatively you can add `wss://live.mysite.com:3000` source into `connect-src` directive. But something tells me that this CSP error is not the only one you have. Therefore, it is better to first understand how the CSP works, and then configure it.

Comment: everything you said was correct but I am using HTTP to create a server, not expressjs.So I am migrating the app to express and I will try

Comment: If you use Helmet - just configure CSP or disable it. Migration is not mandatory.